# Evitar que o Seed duplique dados

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Estou usando este código no Seed para gerar valores na minha tabela, para que não precise digitar no banco, quando alterar algo do meu código e precisar dar um Update no banco, por tanto, ele não está executando, pois até onde intendi, o código abaixo, serve para Adicionar ou atualizar as informações, mas ele está apenas adicionando os valores, e com isto está duplicando.

> context.Estados.AddOrUpdate(x => x.EstadoID, estado);

O método Seed é o seguinte...

```
    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Tribus.Models.Context>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        }

    protected override void Seed(Tribus.Models.Context context)
    {
        IList<Estado> estados = new List<Estado>();
        estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "Acre", Sigla = "AC" });
        estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "Alagoas", Sigla = "AL" });
        estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "Amapá", Sigla = "AP" });
        estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "Amazonas", Sigla = "AM" });
        estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "Bahia", Sigla = "BA" });
        estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "Ceará", Sigla = "CE" });
        estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "Distrito Federal", Sigla = "DF" });
        estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "Espírito Santo", Sigla = "ES" });
        estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "Goiás", Sigla = "GO" });
        estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "Maranhão", Sigla = "MA" });
        estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "Mato Grosso", Sigla = "MT" });
        estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "Mato Grosso do Sul", Sigla = "MS" });
        estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "Minas Gerais", Sigla = "MG" });
        estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "Pará", Sigla = "PA" });
        estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "Paraíba", Sigla = "PB" });
        estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "Paraná", Sigla = "PR" });
        estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "Pernambuco", Sigla = "PE" });
        estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "Piauí", Sigla = "PI" });
        estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "Rio de Janeiro", Sigla = "RJ" });
        estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "Rio Grande do Norte", Sigla = "RN" });
        estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "Rio Grande do Sul", Sigla = "RS" });
        estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "Rondônia", Sigla = "RO" });
        estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "Roraima", Sigla = "RR" });
        estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "Santa Catarina", Sigla = "SC" });
        estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "São Paulo", Sigla = "SP" });
        estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "Sergipe", Sigla = "SE" });
        estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "Tocantins", Sigla = "TO" });
        foreach (Estado estado in estados)
        {
            context.Estados.AddOrUpdate(x => x.EstadoID, estado);
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

com a ajuda de @TobyMosque eu consegui entender o funcionamento do que eu estava fazendo, que também estava certo, porém o verificador de dados, era pela ID e não pelo nome. então eu fiz o seguinte:

```
protected override void Seed(Tribus.Models.Context context)
{
      IList<Estado> estados = new List<Estado>();
      estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "Acre", Sigla = "AC" });
      estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "Alagoas", Sigla = "AL" });
      estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "Amapá", Sigla = "AP" });
      estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "Amazonas", Sigla = "AM" });
      estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "Bahia", Sigla = "BA" });
      estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "Ceará", Sigla = "CE" });
      estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "Distrito Federal", Sigla = "DF" });
      estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "Espírito Santo", Sigla = "ES" });
      estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "Goiás", Sigla = "GO" });
      estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "Maranhão", Sigla = "MA" });
      estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "Mato Grosso", Sigla = "MT" });
      estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "Mato Grosso do Sul", Sigla = "MS" });
      estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "Minas Gerais", Sigla = "MG" });
      estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "Pará", Sigla = "PA" });
      estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "Paraíba", Sigla = "PB" });
      estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "Paraná", Sigla = "PR" });
      estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "Pernambuco", Sigla = "PE" });
      estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "Piauí", Sigla = "PI" });
      estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "Rio de Janeiro", Sigla = "RJ" });
      estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "Rio Grande do Norte", Sigla = "RN" });
      estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "Rio Grande do Sul", Sigla = "RS" });
      estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "Rondônia", Sigla = "RO" });
      estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "Roraima", Sigla = "RR" });
      estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "Santa Catarina", Sigla = "SC" });
      estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "São Paulo", Sigla = "SP" });
      estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "Sergipe", Sigla = "SE" });
      estados.Add(new Estado() { Nome = "Tocantins", Sigla = "TO" });
      foreach (Estado estado in estados)
      {
            context.Estados.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Sigla, estado);
      }
      context.SaveChanges();
}
```

No caso eu só mudei de

```
foreach (Estado estado in estados)
{
     context.Estados.AddOrUpdate(x => x.EstadoID, estado);
}
```

para

```
foreach (Estado estado in estados)
{
     context.Estados.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Sigla, estado);
}
```

trocando o x.EstadoID para x.Sigla pois o que verifica no banco é está parte.

Answer (score 1):

Fabio, para que o AddOrUpdate funcione da maneira correta, você precisar informar os campos que você irá usar para fazer a comparação, e as suas entidades precisam ter estes campos declarados.:

Então você tem duas opções.:

**1. Adicionar a propriedade `EstadoID` nas suas entidades.:**

```
context.Estados.AddOrUpdate(
    x => x.EstadoID, 
    new Estado() { EstadoID = 1, Nome = "Acre", Sigla = "AC" },
    new Estado() { EstadoID = 2, Nome = "Alagoas", Sigla = "AL" },
    new Estado() { EstadoID = 3, Nome = "Amapá", Sigla = "AP" },
    new Estado() { EstadoID = 4, Nome = "Amazonas", Sigla = "AM" },
    new Estado() { EstadoID = 5, Nome = "Bahia", Sigla = "BA" },
    new Estado() { EstadoID = 6, Nome = "Ceará", Sigla = "CE" },
    new Estado() { EstadoID = 7, Nome = "Distrito Federal", Sigla = "DF" },
    new Estado() { EstadoID = 8, Nome = "Espírito Santo", Sigla = "ES" },
    new Estado() { EstadoID = 9, Nome = "Goiás", Sigla = "GO" },
    new Estado() { EstadoID = 10, Nome = "Maranhão", Sigla = "MA" },
    new Estado() { EstadoID = 11, Nome = "Mato Grosso", Sigla = "MT" },
    new Estado() { EstadoID = 12, Nome = "Mato Grosso do Sul", Sigla = "MS" },
    new Estado() { EstadoID = 13, Nome = "Minas Gerais", Sigla = "MG" },
    new Estado() { EstadoID = 14, Nome = "Pará", Sigla = "PA" },
    new Estado() { EstadoID = 15, Nome = "Paraíba", Sigla = "PB" },
    new Estado() { EstadoID = 16, Nome = "Paraná", Sigla = "PR" },
    new Estado() { EstadoID = 17, Nome = "Pernambuco", Sigla = "PE" },
    new Estado() { EstadoID = 18, Nome = "Piauí", Sigla = "PI" },
    new Estado() { EstadoID = 19, Nome = "Rio de Janeiro", Sigla = "RJ" },
    new Estado() { EstadoID = 20, Nome = "Rio Grande do Norte", Sigla = "RN" },
    new Estado() { EstadoID = 21, Nome = "Rio Grande do Sul", Sigla = "RS" },
    new Estado() { EstadoID = 22, Nome = "Rondônia", Sigla = "RO" },
    new Estado() { EstadoID = 23, Nome = "Roraima", Sigla = "RR" },
    new Estado() { EstadoID = 24, Nome = "Santa Catarina", Sigla = "SC" },
    new Estado() { EstadoID = 25, Nome = "São Paulo", Sigla = "SP" },
    new Estado() { EstadoID = 26, Nome = "Sergipe", Sigla = "SE" },
    new Estado() { EstadoID = 27, Nome = "Tocantins", Sigla = "TO" }
);
```

**2. Usar o `Nome` ou `Sigla` como propriedade de comparação**

```
context.Estados.AddOrUpdate(
    x => x.Nome, 
    new Estado() { Nome = "Acre", Sigla = "AC" },
    new Estado() { Nome = "Alagoas", Sigla = "AL" },
    new Estado() { Nome = "Amapá", Sigla = "AP" },
    new Estado() { Nome = "Amazonas", Sigla = "AM" },
    new Estado() { Nome = "Bahia", Sigla = "BA" },
    new Estado() { Nome = "Ceará", Sigla = "CE" },
    new Estado() { Nome = "Distrito Federal", Sigla = "DF" },
    new Estado() { Nome = "Espírito Santo", Sigla = "ES" },
    new Estado() { Nome = "Goiás", Sigla = "GO" },
    new Estado() { Nome = "Maranhão", Sigla = "MA" },
    new Estado() { Nome = "Mato Grosso", Sigla = "MT" },
    new Estado() { Nome = "Mato Grosso do Sul", Sigla = "MS" },
    new Estado() { Nome = "Minas Gerais", Sigla = "MG" },
    new Estado() { Nome = "Pará", Sigla = "PA" },
    new Estado() { Nome = "Paraíba", Sigla = "PB" },
    new Estado() { Nome = "Paraná", Sigla = "PR" },
    new Estado() { Nome = "Pernambuco", Sigla = "PE" },
    new Estado() { Nome = "Piauí", Sigla = "PI" },
    new Estado() { Nome = "Rio de Janeiro", Sigla = "RJ" },
    new Estado() { Nome = "Rio Grande do Norte", Sigla = "RN" },
    new Estado() { Nome = "Rio Grande do Sul", Sigla = "RS" },
    new Estado() { Nome = "Rondônia", Sigla = "RO" },
    new Estado() { Nome = "Roraima", Sigla = "RR" },
    new Estado() { Nome = "Santa Catarina", Sigla = "SC" },
    new Estado() { Nome = "São Paulo", Sigla = "SP" },
    new Estado() { Nome = "Sergipe", Sigla = "SE" },
    new Estado() { Nome = "Tocantins", Sigla = "TO" }
)
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @TobyMosque. ainda não testei pq hoje será um dia corrido pra mim, mas amanhã já vejo se tudo da certo. Valeu mesmo

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, o processo que eu estava fazendo estava certo, porém a verificação estava sendo feita pela ID, e com isso os outros campos estavam duplicando. Com sua resposta eu consegui entender o funcionamento do Seed, e então eu troquei **context.Estados.AddOrUpdate(x => x.EstadoID, estado);** por **context.Estados.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Sigla, estado);** e funcionou. testei usando seu metodo também deu certo, porém como já tinha feito com outros atributos, alterei para o padrão meu. Obrigado

Comment: Entendo, acabou optando pela sugestão 2